# Floating point representation (using bitwise operators)

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

This is a solution to a problem to print the representation of a floating point (i.e : x = (−1)^sign · (1.m 22 m 21 m 20 . . . m 0 ) · 2^(e −bias) ) and I haven't understood some things in it :
1) The use of the union, why ?
2) MANTISSA_MASK and EXPONENET_MASK, what are they for ?
3) the use of & in here :

```
  uint32_t exponent = ( t.bits >> MANTISSA_WIDTH ) & EXPONENT_MASK;
  uint32_t mantissa = ( t.bits  &  MANTISSA_MASK );
```

Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ABSOLUTE_WIDTH 31
#define MANTISSA_WIDTH 23
#define EXPONENT_WIDTH 8
#define EXPONENT_MASK 0xffu
#define MANTISSA_MASK 0x007fffffu
#define EXPONENT_BIAS 127

union float_bits {
  float f;
  uint32_t bits;
};

void print_float( FILE *output, float f ) {
  union float_bits t; t.f = f;

  uint32_t sign_bit = ( t.bits >> ABSOLUTE_WIDTH );
  uint32_t exponent = ( t.bits >> MANTISSA_WIDTH ) & EXPONENT_MASK;
  uint32_t mantissa = ( t.bits  &  MANTISSA_MASK );

  if( sign_bit != 0 ) {
    fprintf( output, "-" );
  }

  if( exponent > 2 * EXPONENT_BIAS ) {
    fprintf( output, "Inf\n" ); /* Infinity */
    return;
  } else if( exponent == 0 ) {
    fprintf( output, "0." ); /* Zero or Denormal */
    exponent = ( mantissa != 0 ) ? exponent + 1 : exponent;
  } else {
    fprintf( output, "1." ); /* Usual */
  }

  for( int k = MANTISSA_WIDTH - 1; k >= 0; --k ) {
    fprintf( output, "%d", ( mantissa >> k ) & 1 );
  }

  if( exponent != 0 || mantissa != 0 ) {
    fprintf( output, " * 2^%d\n", (int) ( exponent - EXPONENT_BIAS ) );
  }
}

int main() {
  FILE *input  = fopen( "floating.in",  "r" ),
       *output = fopen( "floating.out", "w" );

  size_t N; float f;
  fscanf( input, "%zu", &N );

  for( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
    fscanf( input, "%f", &f );
    print_float( output, f );
  }

  fclose( input );
  fclose( output );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a function in `math.h` that can do that called `frexp` the mantissa is between [0.5,1[

Comment: The `union` is there for *type punning*, that is to view some data as two different types. Otherwise if you'd had just a `float`, accessing that `float` always gives you a *value* (of floating point type) and never a bit pattern. The second *view* as an `uint32_t` has the advantage that the value (an unsinged number) has a portable relattionship with the bit pattern that represents it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) The use of the union, why ?

The bit operators are available for integral types only. You cannot convert the floating point number to an integer for obvious reasons. But a union locates the memory of the components overlapping. So by writing into the floating point component and then reading the integral component returns a integral representation of the floating point number. To make that clear: This is *not* the integral value of the floating point number. Using it as an integral number in calculations will give unexpected results. But you can access the bits of the integral number as it would be the bits of the floating point number.

> 2) MANTISSA_MASK and EXPONENET_MASK, what are they for?

Floating point numbers are represented by a number of bits specifying the mantissa (the digit string) and by an exponent part representing the "location" of the digits. After "conversion" of the floating point number into an integral type, this two parts are mixed in the integral value. `MANTISSA_MASK` and `EXPONENT_MASK` (you have a typo in your Q) masks out that parts. `MANTISSA_BITS` moves the exponent to the right place.

> 3) the use of `&` in here:

It is the bit and operator that masks out the bits.

Let's have an – completely virtual – example:

From your code you have 23 bits of mantissa and 8 bits of exponent. One bit of the 32 bits is reserved for the sign. Let's have a number:

```
00000001000010011010011010101010
```

Having 1 sign bit, 8 exponent bits and 23 mantissa bits you can read it like this

```
0 00100010 00010011010011010101010
s exponent --------mantissa-------
```

To get the mantissa you use a mask that only has the mantissa bits set:

```
0 00000000 11111111111111111111111
```

When you bit-and it, only bits that are 1 in both operands are 1, every other bit is 0:

```
0 00100010 00010011010011010101010 A
0 00000000 11111111111111111111111 B
- -------- -----------------------
0 00000000 00010011010011010101010 A&B
```

The mantissa is isolated from the exponent (and now a real integer value representing the mantissa.

To get the exponent, you first shift right the whole word so that the exponent starts from bit 0 (right most):

```
0 00100010 00010011010011010101010 
00000000000000000000000 0 00100010 >> 23 (mantissa bist)
```

To isolate the exponent from the sign bit, you have to bit-and it again:

```
00000000000000000000000 0 00100010 A
00000000000000000000000 0 11111111 B
------------------------------------
00000000000000000000000 0 00100010 A&B
```

Et voíla.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation , I get it know :D .

Answer (score 1):

The format your code assumes is the "Binary interchange floating-point format" as described in IEEE Std 754-2008 (the C standard uses IEC 60559 which is the same) in section 3.4 and even has a diagram (figure 3.1).

For a 32 bit float it is

```
bits:     0        1-9         10-32
      sign bit   exponent     significant (or mantissa)
```

As Jens Gustedt explained in his comment, the union used persuades the compiler to allow a float used as an int (of the same size!) and vice versa. Once you have an integer you can juggle with the bits.

The sign bit is the leftmost bit, you can get it by dividing by 2^31 or by shifting by 31 to the right.

The exponent is in the following 8 bits. The code gets it by shifting right the 23 bit of the size of the significand and masking the exponent off (excluding the sign bit).

They get the significant by just masking of the rightmost 23 bit.

The exponent itself is biased. Why? You want to have  numbers 0 < n < 1 to have a  negative exponent and numbers >= 1 to have a positive exponent. Instead of adding an extra bit for the sign the exponent is halved. Everything below a certain limit (the bias) has to be taken as negative and everything above as positive. To get the sign of the exponent with the correct value you simply subtract the bias.

There are some special values defined by the standard: `Inf` and `NaN` (signaling `NaN` and quiet `NaN`) which are encoded as

- `NaN` (IEEE Std 754-2008 section 6.2.1)

> All binary NaN bit strings have all the bits of the biased exponent field E set to 1 (see 3.4). A quiet NaN bit string should be encoded with the first bit (d1) of the trailing significand field T being 1. A signaling NaN bit string should be encoded with the first bit of the trailing significand field being 0. If the first bit of the trailing significand field is 0, some other bit of the trailing significand field must be non-zero to distinguish the NaN from infinity. In the preferred encoding just described, a signaling NaN shall be quieted by setting d1 to 1, leaving the remaining bits of T unchanged.
>
> For binary formats, the payload is encoded in the p-2 least significand bits of the trailing significant field.

- `Inf` The encodings for `Inf` are not described in such an explicit manner in IEEE-754 (or I haven't found it), only for decimal encodings in section 3.5.2 but it is usually the maximum exponent (all bits set to 1), an unchanged sign bit to distinguish between plus and minus infinity and all of the bits of the significand set to 0 to distinguish it from any finite number. Easily tested for.

The bit-juggling in your code is quite complicated, assumes a specific endianess and that `float` and `uint32_t` have the same endianess, and that `float` is encoded in the single precision format as described in IEEE Std 754-2008/IEC 60559 (you need to check it with the C standard macro `__STDC_IEC_559__`) and that the `union` trick works with the compiler used. If you need something like `frexp(3)` you really should use the build-ins.

A `frexp()` (for a `double`, to lazy to rewrite it. It is from my own version of libmath, written because only a handful of functions were needed and memory was sparse) that assumes a lot less, only that the floating point number conforms to IEC 60559:

```
double frexp(double x, int *eptr)
{
  int sign, exponent;
  int i;

  /*
   * The exponent of an IEEE-754 double (binary64) is an 11-bit large integer
   */
  double ap_2[11] = {
    2.0000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    4.0000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    16.000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    256.00000000000000000000000000000000000,
    65536.000000000000000000000000000000000,
    4294967296.0000000000000000000000000000,
    18446744073709551616.000000000000000000,
    3.4028236692093846346337460743176821146e38,
    1.1579208923731619542357098500868790785e77,
    1.3407807929942597099574024998205846128e154,
    1.7976931348623157e308  // DBL_MAX
  };

  double ap_half[11] = {
    0.50000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0.25000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0.062500000000000000000000000000000000000,
    0.0039062500000000000000000000000000000000,
    1.5258789062500000000000000000000000000e-5,
    2.3283064365386962890625000000000000000e-10,
    5.4210108624275221700372640043497085571e-20,
    2.9387358770557187699218413430556141946e-39,
    8.6361685550944446253863518628003995711e-78,
    7.4583407312002067432909653154629338374e-155,
    5.5626846462680034577255817933310101606e-309    // < DBL_MIN
  };

  if (isinf(x)) {
    *eptr = 0;
    return x;
  }
  if (isnan(x)) {
    *eptr = 0;
    return x;
  }

  if (x == 0.0) {
    *eptr = 0;
    return x;
  }

  exponent = 0.0;
  /*
   * Easier to work with positive values
   */
  if (x < 0) {
    x = -x;
    sign = 1;
  }

  else {
    sign = 0;
  }

  if (x >= 1.0) {
    /*
     * Big steps
     */
    for (i = 0; x >= ap_2[i]; i++) {
      exponent += (1 << i);
      x *= ap_half[i];
    }
    /*
     * Small steps
     */
    if (x < 0.5) {
      while (x < 0.5) {
        x *= 2.0;
        exponent--;
      }
    } else {
      while (x > 1.0) {
        x /= 2.0;
        exponent++;
      }
    }
  } else {
    /*
     * Same as above, but in the opposite direction
     */
    for (i = 0; x < ap_half[i]; i++) {
      exponent -= (1 << i);
      x *= ap_2[i];
    }
    if (x < 0.5) {
      while (x < 0.5) {
        x *= 2.0;
        exponent--;
      }
    } else {
      while (x > 1.0) {
        x /= 2.0;
        exponent++;
      }
    }
  }

  if (sign) {
    x = -x;
  }
  *eptr = exponent;
  return x;
}
```

The function `isinf()` is a bit, how shall I put it, bold and not all compilers might support it:

```
int isinf(double x){
   // TODO: not every compiler might eat this check for Inf
   // GCC-4.8.4  does
   // TCC 0.9.25 does
   // clang 3.4-1ubuntu3 (based on LLVM 3.4) does
   return (x == 1.0/0.0 || x == -1.0/0.0);
}


int isnan(double x){
   return (x != x);
}
```

I replaced the complicated inline computation (as I noted earlier: memory was sparse) of the multiples of 2 by two tables. I hope I did not ruin the rest of the code by doing that.

Aaaaaand I was too slow, as always. This time beaten by Amin Negm-Awad by 43 minutes.